# Can pgfkeys be used to create nested key hierarchies

Tags: pgfkeys, options, kvoptions

I currently have the following following setup (but with many more keys), which works, but isn't as clean as I'd like it.

```
\pgfkeys {
    /title/.is family, /title,
    first/.estore in = \title@first,
    last/.estore in = \title@last,
    city/.estore = \title@city,
}
\renewcommand {\title} [3] [] {
    \pgfkeys{/title,#1}
    {\huge \title@first\ \title@last} \\
    Location: (\title@city) \\
}

\title [
    first = Fred,
    last = Flinstone,
    city = New York\, NY,
]
```

I would like to do something like the following

```
\pgfkeys {
    /title/name/.is family, /title/name,
    first/.estore in = \title@name@first,
    last/.estore in = \title@name@last,
    /title/contact/.is family, /title/contact,
    city/.estore = \title@contact@city,
}
\renewcommand {\title} [3] [] {
    \pgfkeys{/title,#1}
    {\huge \title@name@first\ \title@name@last} \\
    Location: (\title@contact@city) \\
}

\title [
    name = [ % {} instead of [] would be fine as well for me.
        first = Fred,
        last = Flinstone,
    ],
    location = [
        city = New York\, NY,
    ],
]
```

I was inspired by `\setmainfont`, which does a similar thing for `SmallCapsFeatures`

```
\setmainfont [
    Path = font/,
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = MyFont-Bold,
    SmallCapsFeatures = {
        Letters = SmallCaps
    }
] {MyFont-Regular}
```

##### Updates

- Corrected number of arguments from 4 to 3

Comment: yes that's the whole point of key families.

Comment: Why do you specify 4 arguments to `\title` of which one is optional? Your shown use cases only have one optional argument to it, so it should be `\renewcommand{\title}[1][]{...}`. The number of arguments you specify for `\renewcommand` does not correlate to the number of options you define with `\pgfkeys`.

Comment: The 4 is a typo and should have been 3. Also, none of the arguments are supposed optional as I don't provide a default for any.

@percusse, could you provide an example of how to use key families to achieve this?